# SQL syntax error -CONCAT ,Console-BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

This code shows an error at `CONCAT`. I am new to this field and learning on my own. I would be glad if someone clears my question and kindly shares the reason for this problem.

```
SELECT
    Warehouse.warehouse_id
    CONCAT(Warehouse.state,' :',Warehouse.warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM warehouse_orders.Orders Orders) AS total_orders,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT(Ordes.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse_orders.Orders Orders) <= 0.20
            THEN "fulfilled 0-20% of Orders"
        WHEN COUNT(Ordes.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse_orders.Orders Orders) > 0.20
             AND COUNT(Ordes.order_id) / (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM warehouse_orders.Orders Orders) <= 0.60
            THEN "fulfilled 21-60% of Orders"
        ELSE "fulfilled more than 60% of Orders"
    END AS fulfillment_summary
FROM
    warehouse_orders.Orders Warehouse
LEFT JOIN 
    warehouse_orders.Orders Orders ON Orders.warehouse_id = Warehouse.warehouse_id
GROUP BY 
    Warehouse.warehouse_id, warehouse_name
HAVING 
    COUNT(Orders.order_id) > 0
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, remove the non-relevant parts.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you are missing commas.

```
select 
Warehouse.warehouse_id,
CONCAT(Warehouse.state,' :',Warehouse.warehouse_alias) AS warehouse_name,
COUNT(Orders.order_id) AS number_of_orders,
```

Comment: Its still showing error.what to do next?

Comment: Open a new question with the updated data, or edit this question because this question is closed and you will have to edit it in order to reopen it.

Comment: And what's the error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a comma after warehouse_id. Assume the error in CONCAT is because of the missing comma.

--Warehouse.warehouse_id,